# Can special actions in the location card be attempted more than once during a scavenge?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

Can the special actions in the location cards be attempted more than once?  I'm talking about the ones that say "Return N cards to etc" and have you look up a numbered note in the journal.  These are in a black background sideways on the location card

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have enough cards to return and the situation text does not tell you otherwise, you can perform these actions multiple times.

Check Script 600 under Exploration Cards.